# Can I convert rich text field to have plain text output - with carriage returns?

Tags: replace

I am exporting some fields to an XML feed. There is a rich text field with typically 4 paragraphs in it.

The default export kicks out:

```
<p>Some text</p> tags as well as stuff like <strong>.
```

This is easy to remove with |striptags.

However, this results in text that doesn't have proper spacing and removes any intended carriage returns.

I can fix the spacing with a

```
|replace(".", ". ")
```

But I'd rather have the the Paragraphs to still have carriage returns as intended. I know I can add in the right UTF-8 symbol, but I don't want this in the data, I just want the spacing and carriage returns as if it were a plain text field and not to have the UTF-8 symbols in the feed itself.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000D/index.htm

Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Completely untested, but you should be able to do use something like the [Craft-TwigPCRE](https://github.com/victor-in/Craft-TwigPCRE) plugin and some variation of this code:

```
{% set text = "<p>Some text</p> tags as well as stuff like <strong>.|preg_replace('/\<p\>/', '') %}

{% set text = text|preg_replace('/\<\/p\>/', '\\n') %}
```

`\n` is the Line Feed control character for Unix/OSX.

Comment: Many thanks Brad, I will take a look later this afternoon and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Okay, spent some time on this one and ran into several issues.

The feed I tested it on is here: https://flourish-uk.com/indeed2.xml

The issues are that without |raw the text comes in with the symbol codes instead, so &lt; etc instead of the actual <p> tags.

In addition, while the preg_replace works, it struggles when |raw is enabled - nothing appears!

Using preg_replace as a test, I can get it to display the text with the extra symbols - replace them - but \\n appears as just that \\n and not a new line.

Comment: Updated and simplified the XML for now, to show the issues.